# Xcode Is Showing Weird Numbers Next To The Simulator Name

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

When I click on the simulators and devices to test my app on, I see these strange numbers next to them as well as the simulators repeating itself. What do I do to make this large list back to normal. I think I may have done something but I don't know what. Also all of the simulators work the way they should. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Had the same problem... Deleted the extra simulators (from Window>Devices) leaving only one per model and presto. I would like to know though what caused this mess, so if anyone has an idea...

Comment: @Alladinian That fixed the issue, but I too would like to know what caused this to happen

Comment: I still have this problem after I download xcode 7 beta 5

Comment: @OmarAl-Shammary  For some reason, my xcode beta 6 didn't have this issue, can you try it with beta 6?

Comment: still in Xcode 7.3

Comment: top comment solves this issue

Answer (score 0):

According to @alladinian, removing duplicate simulators from **window->Devices & simulators** resolved the issue.